# Is there any difference between predisposition and tendency?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is this sentence

> The most regular patterns originate from a universal human **predisposition** to conceptualize time in terms of space in certain preferential ways.

Can I replace **predisposition** with **tendency** without damaging the intended meaning in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Predisposition** means a bias to do *something* innately without or before being taught, and means *something* happens **all the time**

A **tendency** usually refers to a bias in a repetitive situation, when it happens over and over again, and means *something* happens **most of the time**.  If

> Ducks are **predisposed** to swim before they fly
>
> He has a **tendency** to drink too much every time he goes out and often gets drunk.
>   He is **predisposed** to drink to much and always gets drunk.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, but I don't believe that the word 'predisposition' *always* has to refer to something that happens 'all the time.'  For example, having a genetic predisposition to some condition (e.g. diabetes) means having an increased *likelihood* (not inevitability) of developing that condition later:  https://diabetes.org/diabetes/genetics-diabetes .  Obviously, the word 'tendency' would not work at all in this context, which is another way in which the two words are not 100% synonymous.